# Grails 2.5.1 to Grails 3.3.2

Tags: grails, yaml, grails3

i was using `Grails 2.5.1` and i upgrade to use `Grails 3.3.2` in my old `config.groovy` the below found :

```
contactNumber.domain.size= 8..16
```

i changed it to the below in `application.yml`

```
contactNumber :
 domain :
  size : 8..16
```

Is that right ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use anything other than concrete values in application.yml, after converting a 2.x to a 3.x Grails app I left setting of lists, ranges etc in application.groovy alongside application.yml

Answer (score 3):

> Is that right ?

No.  You have `8..16` in your `application.yml` file and probably expecting it to be evaluated as a Groovy expression which evaluates to a `Range`, which it won't.

If you want to express config values as Groovy expressions, create `grails-app/conf/application.groovy` and use the same syntax there that you would have used in `Config.groovy` in Grails 1 or Grails 2.  That file does not exist by default but if you create it the framework will identify it and use it.  You can have both `application.groovy` and `application.yml` in play concurrently.